# Issue with screen command and ssh-tunnel

Tags: gnu-screen, ssh-tunneling

From 2018 I've been using custom tunnels from remote computers (RPi) and my desktop but lately I'm starting getting problems (regrettably random).
This is the scenario:
Remote computer (Raspberry Pi - RPi) has its own mobile modem. ISP blocks almost all of incoming ports.
Desktop computer (Ubuntu 22-04).
Both have dynamic public IP that renew every 12 hours.
I have a noip.com service in my Desktop to assign it to a no-ip address (let's say DK.noip.com).  So the access from remote to desktop using ssh invoking me@DK.noip.com

At remote I've created a script which checks the tunnel is alive via cron task and creates a new one if not.

At remote I have a paid app installed which also allows me to access from desktop via ssh panel or custom tunnel, but they are a bit slow. Anyway it is useful to check what's going on with my custom tunnel.

The command to create the tunnel from remote:

```
/usr/bin/screen -dmS ssh-Ubuntu /usr/bin/ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R 2222:localhost:22 me@DK.noip.com -g
```

From desktop I simply run `ssh -p 2222 pi@localhost` and I'm in. But many time things happen like

> kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer Connection
> reset by 127.0.0.1 port 2222

after a long while.
Meantime in another desktop shell

```
sudo ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN    

tcp   LISTEN 0      128                            127.0.0.1:2222       0.0.0.0:*    users:(("sshd",pid=1145332,fd=9))    
tcp   LISTEN 0      128                              0.0.0.0:22         0.0.0.0:*    users:(("sshd",pid=542472,fd=3))
tcp   LISTEN 0      128                                [::1]:2222          [::]:*    users:(("sshd",pid=1145332,fd=7))
tcp   LISTEN 0      128                                 [::]:22            [::]:*    users:(("sshd",pid=542472,fd=4))
```

And at remote:

```
ps aux | grep SCREEN
```

outputs

```
pi       11726  0.0  0.2   8444  1976 ?        Ss   13:07   0:00 /usr/bin/SCREEN -dmS ssh-Ubuntu /usr/bin/ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R 2222:localhost:22 me@DK.noip.com -g
```

I described one of the issues I have sometimes that I cannot enter to the created tunnel.

Comment: Does the renewal of the dynamic IP address every 12 hours cause the address to change (on either machine) or not? Do you have any of the 3 forms of keep alive configured (tcp, ssh server, ssh client)?

Comment: @icarus Yes, IP changes every time. In remote it causes the tunnel brake but the cron task (runs every minute) checks there's no tunnel and create it again. From the desktop side happens the same until no-ip app sends it to its server the new public IP remote access via NoIP address. Then remote is able to get connected to desktop when the cron job runs. (first question)

Comment: @icarus Both /etc/ssh/sshd_config have /etc/ssh/sshd-config
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 120
ClientAliveCountMax 5

Comment: You might want to take a look at `autossh`. I'm using it with a similar setup. The `-M` option could be more reactive than ClientAliveInterval, when the ip changes. Also check the DNS you are using, because some servers have a minimum internal TTL and do not honour the 60 seconds from noip, which means a longer wait to get the new IP (since in the meantime you will get the one from the cache).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I remember I tried it some years ago but finally I didn't use it. Don't remember the reason. Anyway I'll give a try again